# Rated current of a three phase DG set

Tags: generator

When the rated current of a 250 KVA DG set is shown as 347.8 A, does it mean that it is the line current or phase current or sum of currents on all phases say R Y B phases

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please clarify your situation, because the question is unclear at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

250 kVA is the full power output of the 3-ph diesel generator and this is 83.33 kVA per phase. The current is line current (same as phase current) and if you divide this current into the 83.33 kVA you get a phase voltage of 239.6 volts.

It might be a 4 wire output with one wire acting as neutral or maybe it's a 3 wire output expecting a balanced load.

Line voltage will be \$\sqrt3\$ times higher than phase voltage at 415 volts.

Answer (score 0):

It is the output current per output phase. power=(3)^.5*V line*I ph
means one can draw 347.8 A from each of the three wires.
vtingole