# Diesel generator set

Tags: generator

When a 250 KVA DG set with four wire out put (3 phases and one neutral wireis working on full load with 0.8 pf lagging, it will deliver 347.8 A which is the rated current.Then what will be the current on R Y B phases? Will the current on all phases will be almost same? Is there any meaning if we add the current on each phase to find the total current?

Comment: Isn't this question virtually the same as this: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/169373/rated-current-of-a-three-phase-dg-set asked a short while ago by the op?

Answer (score 2):

A 250 kVA three-phase alternator, rated 415V phase to phase, outputs a current of 348 amps per phase. (Note: the power factor is irrelevant.)

Assuming a balanced load:

- The red phase current will be 348 amps, at 0 degrees phase angle.
- The white phase current will be 348 amps, at 120 degrees phase angle.
- The blue phase current will be 348 amps, at 240 degrees phase angle.

If your load is unbalanced, then the red, white and blue phase currents will be different.

Adding the red, white, and blue phase currents **at a particular instant in time** will give the neutral (residual, unbalance) current. A balanced load has zero neutral current. An unbalanced load has non-zero neutral current.

Adding the RMS values of the currents (i.e. 348 A + 348 A + 348 A = 1,044 A) is meaningless.

---

Disclaimer: Don't mess with electrical installations unless you are trained, deemed competent, and authorised to do so.